# Redact Bigrams from a List Based on Matching Unigrams

Tags: python, pandas, list, nlp, boolean

From a list of bigrams, I need to redact bigrams that do not have at least one term that ***exactly*** matches at least one term in a list of unigrams.

*The Two Lists*

`bigram_list = ['computer vision', 'data excellence', 'data visualization']`

`unigram_list = ['excel', 'tableau', 'visio', 'visualization']`

*The Objective*

`cleaned_bigrams = ['data visualization']`

*What I've Tried*

I tried adapting this approach here, but failed: [Removing separate list of items from another list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188896/removing-separate-list-of-items-from-another-list-in-python-3-x)

I also tried this, but couldn't get it to work: [Get rid of unigrams in a list if contained within bigrams or trigrams python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458764/get-rid-of-unigrams-in-a-list-if-contained-within-bigrams-or-trigrams-python)

I tried to adapt from a previous question I asked, but couldn't get that going: [Create new boolean fields based on specific bigrams appearing in a tokenized pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147799/create-new-boolean-fields-based-on-specific-bigrams-appearing-in-a-tokenized-pan)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide, and would appreciate an upvote if you think this is a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
bigram_list = ["computer vision", "data excellence", "data visualization"]
unigram_list = ["excel", "tableau", "visio", "visualization"]

# Init a dict for counting number of match
counts = {key: 0 for key in bigram_list}

# Count number of match for each bigram
for big in bigram_list:
    for uni in unigram_list:
        if uni in big.split(" "):
            counts[big] += 1

# Filter
cleaned_bigrams = [item for item in bigram_list if counts[item] > 0]
```

```py
print(cleaned_bigrams)
# Output
['data visualization']
```

Comment: Very artful how you did this, and it runs quickly for my dataset. Using the dictionary to count matches is clever. Much appreciated!